# How to make a hyperlink inside cell text?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-word, ms-office

How can I make a hyperlink to another page or document inside a cell of Excel. 
Example:

[image]

That whole text is inside a cell. But i want to make "FOGC-FP01" a hyperlink to another page or document and "for update" keeps being text ??

Answer (score 2):

Or you could you the inbuilt hyperlink () function http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010062412.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Click on the cell you want to make a hyperlink.  Go to insert>hyperlink.

In the window that pops up use **place in this document**.

Gordon

[image: add hyperlink]

I don't think its possible to just make part of the cell string a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a very similar example,so i hope it will  help.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var wbosszes = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;
        ws.Name = "test";

        xla.Visible = true;

        List<Content> forExample = new List<Content>();

        var oneTestItem = new Content { ContentPath = "questions/tagged/excel", ContentTitle = "any text" };
        forExample.Add(oneTestItem);

        for (int i = 0; i < forExample.Count; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[1, 2] = "any text";

            int range1 = i + 4;
            var range = ws.get_Range("C" + range1, "C" + range1);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink link = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink)
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add(range, "http://stackoverflow.com/" + forExample[i].ContentPath, Type.Missing,
                              "Any Tooltip text!!!! e.g(http/://stackoverflow.com/forExample[i].ContentPath)",
                              forExample[i].ContentTitle);
        }
    }

class Content 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// That is a Content Title (e.g: oneArticle)
    /// </summary>
    public string ContentTitle { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// That is a Content link (e.g: http://stackoverflow/questions )
    /// </summary>
    public string ContentPath { get; set; }
}
```